# Populate Django Form field-labels from a database model when calling this Form thru a sidebar menu item

Tags: django, forms, label, field, auto-populate

I am new to Python, Django and web programming, so may be this is a dumb question or conceptually a wrong logic. I am trying to call an entry Form from sidebar menu item and want this Form fields to have labels from a database model, so that same form/database model can be used for different purposes. The sidebar menu is populated using Django-MPTT. This form pop ups normally with it's original labels when clicking the menu item, but if I try to set it's field labels from database model with relative labels, it gives error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'task_t3'. May be it is due "GET" request initiated on menu item click. Any solution to achieve this? Following is code lines from views.py where this error occur:

```
    ctlobj = TaskControl.objects.filter(task_group_no=5)
    taskdetail_form = TaskDetailForm()
    taskdetail_form.task_3.label = ctlobj.task_t3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by looping over variable ctlobj and then assigning values to field label in required form:

```
ctlobj = TaskControl.objects.filter(task_group_no=5)
taskdetail_form = TaskDetailForm()
for obj in ctlobj:
    taskdetail_form.task_3.label = obj.task_t3
```